# When testing toString, why is calling toString required?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tostring

I've overwritten the toString method of my class. When testing the toString method, I've been left wondering why calling toString is required.

Let me elaborate -

toString in class People:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ("This Object is called " + this.name + ". For a list of weekdays: " + this.dates);
}
```

Working Test Case:

```
    @Test
    Human Tom = new Human("Tom"); // constructor creates an ArrayList<weekDay> named dates
    weekDay someDay = new weekDay("Thursday");
    Tom.addDate(someDay);  // adds someDay to the ArrayList
    String result = ("This Object is called " + this.name + ". For a list of weekdays: " + Tom.dates);
    assertEquals(Tom.toString(), result);
```

`assertEquals(Tom.toString(), result)` will work fine. But, when instead I try `assertEquals(Tom, result)` eclipse will write something like "expected `x`" but was "`y`". Yet, "`y`" has the exact same content as "`x`". Why is the need for explicitly calling `toString()`?

Comment: Oh crap. I think I got it, it might be because Tom is an object and I need a string in order for the equals method to work. Is this correct?

Comment: actually it is more like if you want to test `toString()`, `toString()` must be called... [:-) (unless the test framework had a method `assertToStringEquals()` {that calls `toString()`})

Comment: BTW, little point, but it's `assertEquals(expected, actual)`, so the call should be `assertEquals(result, Tom.toString());`.  Doesn't affect the pass/fail, of course, but if the test fails saying "expected Fred but got Tom" could save you or others from a wild-goose-chase diving into the code looking for why it's not returning "Fred".   This is also why Hamcrest-style is much nicer, with it's explicit `assertThat(Tom.toString(), is(equalTo(result)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
assertEquals(Tom.toString(), result);
```

This is equivalent to writing:

```
Tom.toString().equals(result);
```

Which compares the two `String` values. When you attempt to do this:

```
assertEquals(Tom, result);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Tom.equals(result);
```

Which is now invoking the `.equals()` method on your `People` class (if you defined one), or Object#equals if you did not.

Eclipse is printing out the toString() method after your test fails to give you details of the error, which is unfortunately confusing in this scenario.